# fread() from .dat file

Tags: c, fopen, fread

I have a `.dat` file which contains data such as name, town and telephone number. I did manage to open the file and read the first line of entries in the a `while` loop but after that, it will simply repeat the same thing over and over again. Here is the bit of code:

```
while(fread(&customer.town,1,sizeof(customer.town), fopen(input,"r" "b")) ==1 )
  {
    printf("%i. Town...........: %s\n",i,&customer.town);
  }
```

edit:
as of now the code looks like this:

```
customer pp[3];
...  

fread(pp, sizeof(customer), 9, fp);

        for (i=0;i<=5;i++)
            {
             printf("%i\t%s\n",++j,pp[i].town);
            }
        getch();
```

the only problem i have with that one is that it shows the first entry just fine but after that it "eats" the first few letters.

edit 2

Details: each sturctur variable has several entrys. I also focus on just town for now.
Problem: Only out puts 1 Town correct the other entrys are either blank or random chars.

current code:

```
 #include <conio.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    #define FILENAME "customer.dat"

    int main()
    {
    typedef struct Satz
        {
        char        town[11];
        int         costumerid[20];
        }test __attribute__((packed));

    test output[20];
    FILE *fp;
    int size=sizeof(output[20].town);
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int limit=0;
    fp=fopen(FILENAME,"rb");


    if (fp==NULL)
        {
        printf("Couldnt open the file:%s!\n", FILENAME);
        getch();
        return(-1);
        }


   printf("Limit: %i \n\n", limit=fread(output,1,size, fp));

    for (i=0;i<limit;i++)
        {
        printf("%i\t%s\n",++j,output[i].town);
        }
    getch();
    }
```

Console Output:

```
Limit: 11

1       Leipzig
2
3
4       ░w
5
6       hðv
7       J
8       \
9       o
10      i
11      i
```

2-11 are random.

edit 3

```
    int main()
{
typedef struct Satz
    {
    char town[11];
    }__attribute__((packed))test;

    test output[30];
    FILE *fp;
    int size=sizeof(output[20].town);
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int limit=0;
    fp=fopen(FILENAME,"rb");


    if (fp==NULL)
        {
        printf("Couldnt open the file:%s!\n", FILENAME);
        getch();
        return(-1);
        }


   printf("Limit: %i \n\n", limit=fread(output,sizeof(test),11, fp));

    for (i=0;i<=limit;i++)
        {
        printf("%i\t%s\n",++j,output[i].town);
        }
    getch();
    }
```

output:

```
Limit: 5

1       Leipzig
2       alle
3       rlin
4       tock
5       erin
6       us
```

expected output:

```
1      Leipzig
2      Halle
3      Berlin
4      Rostock
5      Schwerin
6      Cottbus
```

Comment: Why are you opening the file in multiple places?

Comment: the code got messy after many redos, started clean now and got it somewhat working now.

Comment: In the new code, there are only 3 customers in that `pp` array, but the `for` loop takes the index `i` to 5, so it's out of bounds when used in the `printf()`.  Even for quick and dirty testing, you ought to fix that.  Otherwise, expect to get unpredictable results, possibly including crashes (depends on what you do).

Comment: @yuuki, Four suggestions:  1) Change `if (fopen( ... == NULL)` to `if (fp == NULL)`  (don't need to open a second time, and `fp` validity is what you want to confirm)  2)  Add a `printf()` of `limit` after a value has been assigned by `fread()`.   3)  In the `for` loop, change `<=limit` to `< limit`, because `i` is zero-based, so setting it to `limit` would go out of bounds.  4)  Please post the data being read, too.

Comment: i added it in the post, also not all of the 11 slots have to be filled with data.

Comment: @yuuki, Thanks for accepting my suggestions, and posting output.  The `sizeof()` returns the size of the `.town` field, which is declared as 11 characters.  So `size` becomes 11, and `fread()` successfully reads 11 bytes, and returns a value of 11, stored in `limit`.  But then `limit` is used to index structures of `output`, not characters within `town`.

Comment: Is `customer.dat` a text file?

Comment: its a .dat file. when opened with an editor it just shows leizig and random chars. but when opened with an provided datviewer it show the full content. there also isnt any kind of encryption in place.

Comment: @yuu, It sounds like you want `limit = fread( output, sizeof( test ), numTests, fp );` once you know the number of test structures stored inside the .dat file.  Although, it would be more conventional to read one struct at a time, print/process it, and loop to the next, until the file is exhausted.

Comment: If I understand what you are trying, you are reading the file incorrectly. You need to read every columns, not just the town and then print just the town. Your new `fread()` should be `limit=fread(output, sizeof(test), 20, fp)`. The value returned by `fread()` is the number of records it successfully read.

Comment: @yuuki, `numTest` is just the hypothetical name I gave for number of test structures in the file.  I do not know of a standard format for `.dat` and have been assuming it is data organized in a custom format.

Comment: @alvits limit=0 is the result of this.

Comment: So it seems that `struct Satz` is not aligned with what is stored in the file and it failed to even read 1 record. By any chance, did you copy my comment before I edited it? I had `20` and `sizeof(test)` in the wrong positions in `fread()`.

Comment: @alvits its aligned with the .file atleast its the structur the datviewer reports.

Comment: Let's try to debug it, shall we? You were successful in reading the first record although you only read the town but not the whole record. If you try `limit=fread(output, sizeof(test), 2, fp)` check if you are successful in reading 2 records and try printing `output[1].town`.

Comment: @ alvits limit 2. The magic number seems to be 5. he wont got higher then a limit of 5. The dat file viewer reports 6 cities but this is excepted since the pc counts the 0 too. So its 0,1,2,3,4,5.

Comment: @alvits Now the output needs work. 1. one is shwon fully (7 letters). 2-5 one shows only 4 letters and the 6 is just 2 letters.

Comment: I think it is best to post the test code, the output and the expected output. Let's proceed from there.

Comment: @alvits done under edit 3

Comment: It means your structure, even though packed, is still bigger than the record size stored in the file such that reading record 1 reads beyond into the first byte of record 2. Reading record 2 then reads beyond into the first 2 bytes of record 3. Your structure is 1 byte longer than what is stored in the file.

Comment: The most logical place where you could be 1 byte longer is the length of member `town`. Try reducing the member `town` to `char town[10]`.

Comment: @alvits doesnt help. if i got to low he puts in random chars and if too high he will show nothing.

Comment: I noticed the the structures in edit 2 and edit 3 are not the same. And you claimed it is aligned with the file. So which one is aligned? I bet neither is aligned. Hence the erroneous output.

Comment: If the structure is not aligned with the file, there is no magic to help you fix the code. You need to get the exact structure or `fread()` will never ever get it right.

Comment: i just left the other one out here on site since i dont process is currently. in source code on my pc it written. and its alligned.

Comment: Are you the owner of the code generating this dat file? If you are, you should also post the structure used in that code and the `fwrite()` call.

Comment: And lastly, because I am blinded without knowledge of your file contents, try to debug it by adjusting the `fread()` to read with 1 less byte. `limit=fread(output, sizeof(test) - 1, 20, fp)`

Comment: the only thing i know about this while is the structur.
`struct Satz
{
  char town[11];
  int costumerid[20];
};`

Comment: And apparently that structure is 1 byte longer than what is stored in the file.

Comment: the only thing it changes is the limit. 5 to 6

Comment: So when the limit changed to 6, the town should also change. What is the effect on the new town now that there is 1 extra town? Did you print all the towns?

Comment: hmm now that i think about it. could it be theoretical be that a control sign like for example for an new line is interfering. if the pc reads it it would explain the 1 letter missing on the 2 nd one. and since it is summing up we could end up with just us on 6th.

@alvits the 7th is just empty.

Comment: If the record is separated by a newline or an extra byte, your structure will be shorter. But you are reading 1 byte more than what you need to read. It's the other way around.

Comment: Or maybe I misunderstood your comment. If the extra byte is getting printed and causing the town name to be overwritten, then you are reading 1 byte shorter.

Comment: Try changing your structure to add an extra byte holder at the end.

Comment: Test both `struct Satz { char town[10]; int costumerid[20]; };` and `struct Satz { char town[12]; int costumerid[20]; };`. See which one works.

Comment: i can add buffer of 1 before he corrupts the data. And sub 2 before he does the same.

Comment: he also seems to ignore the `__attribute__((packed))` since it doesnt change a thing even if i leave it away.

Comment: Since none of my suggestions seem to work, the last resort is to post the hex values of the content of your file. This is the most accurate representation of your file. This way I can give you a working code.

Comment: can i send it to you somehow. dont wanna post it openly.

Comment: Run `hexdump -b customer.dat`. We know that your second record's town is `Halle`. Look for the sequence of numbers `110` `141` `154` `154` `145`. These sequence of bytes correspond to ascii `Halle`. Each 3 digit octal number represent a byte. Count the number of bytes starting from the beginning until you reach the last byte before these sequence. Tell me how many bytes there are. Note that the first column of output should not be counted. The first column display the offset that it is displaying.

Comment: In your code, print the size of test. This should be equal to the number of bytes you just counted.

Comment: 0x170 48 30 6C 6C 65 are corresponding hex values in the data files.
Leipzig on the other hand in right in the begininng:
0x000 4C 65 69 70 7A 69 67
Berlin has an offset of 0x2E0. so i guess the offset is always hex 170

Comment: The content of the file isn't exactly what you thought it has. The sequence `48` `30` `6C` `6C` `65` corresponds to `H0lle`. Notice the `0` (`30`) ?

Comment: no it was just a typo by me its 61

Comment: The offset is `0x170` as you have pointed out. That's `368` in decimal. Can you print the size of your structure?

Comment: printf("size: %i",sizeof(test)); reports 372. So the offest is 4 numbers smaller then the structur

Comment: And so it seems the structure you posted isn't the structure in your code. Your code shows a structure of 372 bytes but what's posted here is only 92 bytes.

Comment: You need to adjust your structure to fit a 368 byte record.

Comment: i i go down totown[8] i result in this:

`1       Leipzig
2       3âBHalle
3       MB33BBerlin
4       B\ÅUB
WæBRostock
5       ©_B\ÅIB
WëBSchwerin
6
7       5B`

Comment: The `__attribute__((packed))` also affects the size when in the right place. It should be placed right after typedef struct. It should be `typedef struct  __attribute__((packed)) Satz`. Check the size using this syntax and make them align to 368 bytes.

Comment: it wont get smaller without glitching the output even more.
https://1ty.me/ygSeoJjg (link will delete automaticly after one time press)
here the hex data and structur for now i just want to see how i can read out the towns. The rest i want to figure out myself.

Comment: Your record size is 371, not 368. Here's what I have now `struct __attribute__((packed)) wetter
{
  char ort[11];
  float temp[30];
  unsigned short niederschalg[30];
  unsigned short luftdruck[30];
  float luftfeuchte[30];
};`

Comment: i dont see a difference.

Comment: If you print its size it says 371. Yours says 372. The attribute packed shortens it by 1 byte (packed).

Comment: i always get 372. strange

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I am using gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16) (GCC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input file you sent me has some extra records added by `xxd` when converted back to binary after the last legitimate entry that caused the `fread()` to read 14 extra records of empty values.

Here's the code that worked on my test.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
struct __attribute__((packed)) wetter
{
  char ort[11];
  float temp[30];
  unsigned short niederschalg[30];
  unsigned short luftdruck[30];
  float luftfeuchte[30];
};
    struct wetter output[20];
    int limits, i;
    printf("The size of record is %d\n", sizeof(struct wetter));
    FILE *fp=fopen("orig","r");
    printf("The limit is %i\n", limits=fread(output,sizeof(struct wetter),20,fp));
    for(i=0;i<limits;i++)
        printf("%d\t%s\n", i+1, output[i].ort);
}
```

And Here's the output of the code.

```
The size of record is 371
The limit is 20
1   Leipzig
2   Halle
3   Berlin
4   Rostock
5   Schwerin
6   Cottbus
7   
8   
9   
10  
11  
12  
13  
14  
15  
16  
17  
18  
19  
20
```

Without the attributes packed the output shows similar to yours.

```
The size of record is 372
The limit is 20
1   Leipzig 
2   alle    
3   rlin    
4   tock    
5   erin    
6   us  
7       
8       
9       
10      
11      
12      
13      
14      
15      
16      
17      
18      
19      
20
```

One caveat when setting attributes. This typedef will cause compiler to ignore 'packed' attribute.

```
typedef struct wetter
{
  char ort[11];
  float temp[30];
  unsigned short niederschalg[30];
  unsigned short luftdruck[30];
  float luftfeuchte[30];
}test __attribute__((packed));
```

This typedef will not cause compiler to ignore 'packed' attribute.

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) wetter
{
  char ort[11];
  float temp[30];
  unsigned short niederschalg[30];
  unsigned short luftdruck[30];
  float luftfeuchte[30];
}test;
```

For structures that are not `typedef`ed, the issue doesn't show.

Comment: so i just need to find a way to ignore the xxd in the program?

Comment: @yuuki - No. I had to convert the hexdump you sent me to the original format. `xxd` is a tool that reverses the hexdump. It has nothing to do with your effort.

Comment: @yuuki - You miscounted the offset. You just read the offset on the left column but your record didn't start exactly on the offset printed on the side.

Comment: @yuuki - Are you sure you are passing the size and number of records in the right order to fread? Correct: `fread(output,sizeof(struct wetter),20,fp)`. Wrong: `fread(output, 20, sizeof(struct wetter),fp)`.

Comment: not yet. Limit is working again. no idea what he didnt like a simple codeblocks restart did help through. and sadly he still seems to ignore the `__attribute__`

Comment: Can you compile with `-Wall -Wextra`? Look for messages such as _warning: ‘packed’ attribute ignored_.

Comment: -------------- Build: Release in wetter (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -O2  -c C:\Users\Yuuki\Desktop\wetter2\wetter\main.c -o obj\Release\main.o
mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Release\wetter.exe obj\Release\main.o  -s  
Output file is bin\Release\wetter.exe with size 8.50 KB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

Comment: Sorry I assumed you are working on a Linux system. There's a difference between Linux and Windows. Try using `pragma pack`. Here's a reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253935(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @yuuki - it looks like [packed attribute is broken on mingw32](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52991).

Comment: i dont use visual basics either so it could be problematic even more so since the goal is pure ansi c. Right now i am implementing the 64 mingw version. It could be that 32bit version just doesnt know this line.

Comment: got it fixed with -mno-ms-bitfields as compiler flag.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. Sorry I didn't figure that one out. I don't use `mingw` compiler :/

Comment: no problem you did helped me pretty much. And i also learnt some new things from you.

what compiler do you use?

Comment: I use `gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16) (GCC)`. It's on x86_64 RedHat/Fedora/CentOS distros.

Comment: Hmm I am think I will try if it runs under cygwin or is importable to ccodeblocks

Comment: Oh you mean `fopen()` is failing. Print the value returned by `strerror(errno)` just after calling `fopen()`. You will need to include `errno.h`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is re-executing `fopen()` with every loop.  See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/ for an example of proper use, place your `fopen()` before your `while`, and your loop should then work fine.

Specifically, you need to allocate a `FILE*`, give it a value from `fopen()`, check it for failure, then use that `FILE*` in your `fread()` call.

Comment: thanks for the answer, managed to make it semi working but not at the goal yet.

Comment: @yuuki, What does the code look like now?  Also, what remains to be done to reach your goal?